# Windows 10 IoT Core - video open close

Tags: c#, windows, raspberry-pi2, windows-iot-core-10

I've been working project in Raspberry Pi 2 running Windows 10 IoT Core. Project subject sensor triggering with open a video. 
But I am getting the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in ProjeVol1.exe but
>   was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The application called an interface that was
>   marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E
>   (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

Code:

```
private void SensorPin_ValueChanged(GpioPin sender, GpioPinValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Sensor Tetiklendi");
    if (args.Edge == GpioPinEdge.FallingEdge)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Falling Edge");
        ledPin.Write(GpioPinValue.High);
        VideoAc();

    }
    else if (args.Edge == GpioPinEdge.RisingEdge)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Rising Edge");
        ledPin.Write(GpioPinValue.High);

    }
}


public void VideoAc()
{
    video.AutoPlay = true;
    video.Play();
    video.MediaEnded += Video_MediaEnded;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely the sensor event comes from a different thread than the UI's one, and that gets the framework angry.

Try to enclose the `VideoAc` call in a dispatcher synchronization as explained in this piece: [UWP update UI from Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149767/uwp-update-ui-from-task)

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
    VideoAc();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying it.