# How to Call a method in UI thread from another running thread in UWP?

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp, task

I want to call `Update(int i)` from inside of the Thread. I used to use `BeginInvoke()`, but it isn't available in UWP.

```
public class Viewmodel
{
 Viewmodel()
 {
   //start task
   var mainTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
     MyThread();
   });
 }
 private void MyThread()
 {
    int i;
    while(condition)
    {
      //do somethings
      Update(i) 
    }
 }
 private Update(int i)
 {
   //do somethings
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below should work.

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
() =>
{
    // update your UI here
    Update(i) 
});
```

Comment: Since the original question mentioned running in a view-model class, you could use `this.Dispatcher` instead. Relying on `MainView` will cause breaks if the app ever has more than one view.

Comment: Where would I use this code, inside Task when I  would want to call `Update()`?

Comment: @AmirHusseinNargesian you can just put this inside Update() function and add your logic  within the Dispatch handler.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below code to run your code :

```
await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High/* the rank */,
() =>
{
    // run the code
});
```

And I have another way to do it

```
  await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal /*the rank*/, () => { // run the code  });
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38175976/6116637

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority) clearly says not to use the value `High`.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Thx, but I want to say you can set the rank in this.