# Windows IoT Raspberry Pi 3 c# MediaPlayer.mediaEnded

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I am new to this. 
I am trying to do a Audio Message Player on Rasp Pi 3 with Win IoT core.
I manage to play audio file from my USB thumbdrive but I need to know when the audio file has completed playing.

```
 mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
 mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += MediaPlayer_MediaEnded;

 private void MediaPlayer_MediaEnded(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
    {
        GeneralMessage.Text = "Message Complete!";
    }
```

i get an error message with the above code.

```
System.Exception occurred
  HResult=0x8001010E
  Message=The application called an interface that was marshalled for a 
different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))
```

Please help.

Comment: You are trying to modify a UI Element from a thread that is not the UI Thread. Usually you would use something like "Control.Invoke" to marshal that modification to the UI Thread.

Comment: Is there anyway for me to display a string to indicated the file has completed playing?

Comment: Yes, use Invoke on GeneralMessage. I'll try to find an example ...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-make-thread-safe-calls-to-windows-forms-controls

Comment: pardon my knowledge on c# may i know how to invoke a thread?

Comment: Not sure if this is applicable to Win IoT core, though.

Comment: thanks.. I will try it and update here to share.

Comment: I just saw, it will probably **not** be applicable. Maybe this will help instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38207907/982149 It is about updating an int Property, but you can use Progress<string>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i manage to solve the invoke thingy.. code as follow

```
private async void MediaPlayer_MediaEnded(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            GeneralMessage.Text = "Done playing.";

     });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of your problem is that, UI changes must be made on the UI thread but MediaEnded event is raised on a different thread.

In windows IoT Core, when you update the element in UI from another thread, please use the Dispatcher.RunAsync method.

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
     //this part is run on a background thread...

     await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, 
        ()=> 
        {
             //this part is being executed back on the UI thread...
             GeneralMessage.Text = "Message Complete!";
        });
});
```

Please reference here [Media items, playlists, and tracks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-playback-with-mediasource).This article showed how to use MediaSource , and included the operations performed within a CoreDispatcher.RunAsync call.

Comment: Hi Micheal, thanks. But it shows 'the name Task.Run does not exist in current context'. Any idea?