# Tasks and Interface in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, interface, task

I'm building an app that uploading files to Google Drive. WHen I'm binding properties and inoked them, it crash with this error:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'`

my code ->

MyFiles class:

```csharp
propfull Progress<IUploadProgress> progress;
propfull double Value;
propfull string Name;
propfull double Size;
propfull string fullpath;

//each one of properties has `OnPropertyChanged()` in SET
//More properties...

public virtual void OnPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    Debug.WriteLine($"~~~~~~{propertyName} invoked!");
}

public MyFiles(StorageFile file)
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.Path);
    this.fullpath = file.Path
    this.Size = fileInfo.Length;
    this.Value = 0;
    this.Name = file.name;
    this.progress = new Progress<IUploadProgress>();
    this.progress += progressChanged; //prog.Report() is calling this
}

private void progressChanged(object sender, IUploadProgress e)
{
    if (e.Status == UploadStatus.Uploading)
    {
        this.Value = (e.BytesSent * 100) / this.Size; 
        //invoke(this.value) property.
        //Binding to ProgressBar.Value
    }
}
```

the `MediaPage.xaml` file:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="myListView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="600" Width="700">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="70">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,20" FontSize="20"  Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="Yu Gothic UI Semibold"/>
                        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Value}" Tag="{Binding Name}" Height="5" Width="200"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<Button x:Name="upload_btn" Click="ButtonClick" Height="40" Width="150" Content="Upload All Files"/>
```

the code in `MediaPage.xaml.cs`

```
public MediaPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    SavedData.files = new ObservableCollection<MyFiles>();
    StorageFile file = ...; // testing file
    SavedData.files.Add(new MyFiles(file));

    myListView.ItemsSource = SavedData.files;
}

private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SavedData.files.Count; i++)
    {
        DriveClass.UploadFile(i, SavedData.files[i].progress); //(index,progress)
    }
}
```

the `DriveClass` code:

```
public void UploadFile(int index, IProgress<IUploadProgress> prog)
{

    try
    {
        StorageFile file = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync([SavedData.files[index].fullpath).AsTask().Result;

        var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
        {
            Name = Path.GetFileName(file.Name),
            MimeType = "application/octet-stream"
            
        };

        using (var stream = file.OpenStreamForReadAsync().Result)
        {
            

            var request = this.drive.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, "application/octet-stream");

            request.ProgressChanged += (IUploadProgress progressInfo) =>
            {
                if (progressInfo.Status == UploadStatus.Completed)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"done!");
                    prog.Report(progressInfo);
                }
                else if (progressInfo.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Failed To Upload Into Google Drive");
                    prog.Report(progressInfo);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(progressInfo.BytesSent + " has sent");
                    prog.Report(progressInfo);

                }
            };

            request.ChunkSize = 262144;
            request.Upload();

            var uploadedFile = request.ResponseBody;
            Debug.WriteLine($"File uploaded: {uploadedFile.Name} ({uploadedFile.Id})");

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Cant uplaod the file because -> " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

this is the whole cade. everything works fine until I press the button and calling to `UploadFile()`.

In `UploadFile()`, when the request.progressChanged is active, it called to `files[i].progress.ProgressChanged()`.

`ProgressChanged()` is updating the `files[i].Value` and `invoke()` to change the `ProgressBar.Value = "{Binding Value}"`

the app crash in the `Invoke()` line, because I can't update the UI.

Comment: ...why aren't you using `async`/`await`?

Comment: Your `ProgressChanged` event-handler is being invoked on a different thread. You need to use `Control.BeginInvoke` from within your event-handler.

Comment: @Dai how to do that? I'm pretty new in this

Comment: @Dai I can't find the Control.BeginInvoke

Comment: If I understand your post correctly, `prog.Report` is throwing an exception. Yet you did not give us the code for `prog.Report`. You gave us all this other code for some reason. Can you edit your question?

Comment: @ArielP I still do not see anything that tells me what type `prog` is or the implementation of `prog.Report`.

Comment: @JohnWu the prog works fine. The problem is the `Invoke()` in the 'MyFiles' class. It crashes there when it notify to the progressbar in listview

Comment: @JohnWu the `prog` notify to `myfiles.value` that get crashed with System.Runtime error

Comment: What is the issue? Why can't you share the actual code that raises the exception?

Comment: @JohnWu This is the code. The `UploadFile()`, the `"MyFiles"` class, and the XAML code. It's just it. I shortcut the propfull and the code of `Invoke()` and more unrelevant properties like filepath and stuff. The problem is that the invoke updating the listview in the middle of the UploadFile(). Usually the `Dispatcher.RunAsync` fixing this. But here I can't add the Dispatcher to 
`OnPropertyChange()` in "MyFiles" class. I want to update the listview from the `UploadFile()` function. The `prog.Report()` is calling to `ProgressChange()` in MyFiles class.

Comment: The code breaks when the `prog.Report` reporting that the `UploadStatus = Uploading` because when it uploading, the `ObserveCollection<MyFiles> myfiles[index].Value` changed and the UI changed with it. I'm trying very hard to explain that I'm really sorry about my English @JohnWu

Comment: @JohnWu I edit the code again. I can copy the whole code but it is just irrelevant.

Comment: @ArielP - Please copy in all of the code. It is relevant. You're struggling to identify the issue in your code but somehow you're confident that you've shown us enough code for us to solve it? You haven't. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnWu I edit the question and copied the code. I hope now its better

Comment: found answer. uploading this now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, I found something that helped.

the way to Invoke the properties that the UI is connected to, is to add this kind of dispatcher to `OnPropertyChanged()`.

```
public async virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    });

}
```

After adding this `Dispatcher`, the code was running but the app was stuck. so, I turn the `UploadFile()` to `Task` instead of `void` and added the folowing code to `ButtonClick()` event in `MediaPage.xaml.cs`

```
Task UploadFileTask = Task.Run(() => DriveClass.UploadFile(index,progress));
```

This also will continue the uploading progress.

[image: Here how the ProgressBar looks and what I wanted to do]

I saw the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149767/uwp-update-ui-from-task).